# How to fetch user github repository by just enter user id in android

Tags: android, github, github-api

I want to fetch github repository of a user in android. In my application I just to user enter a github user id and show his repository. Does github provide any API for this. How I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout the [GtiHub API List Repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories):

```
GET /users/:username/repos
```

You can use [`gitskarios/GithubAndroidSdk`](https://github.com/gitskarios/GithubAndroidSdk) (marked deprecated, [but it actually is just not maintained](https://github.com/gitskarios/GithubAndroidSdk/issues/59), but still recent enough)
Other [Java libraries do exist though](https://developer.github.com/libraries/).